# Can we use both instead of and after in triggers?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I want to define `instead of` for `insert` and `update` operations but `after` for the `delete` operation.
Is it possible? Or, do I need to write an additional trigger for that? For example, no rows can be removed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger ON my_table
instead of INSERT,UPDATE for DELETE
AS
BEGIN

.......
END
```

Comment: No - the type (instead, after) of trigger is specific. You can create any number of triggers but each trigger is of a single type. But to prevent deletion, it is better to use permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you would need 2 triggers.  Only 1 `INSTEAD OF` trigger may be create per DML action type per table, although DML action types may be combined, as in this case, i.e. both INSERT and UPDATE.

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger_instead_of_ins_upd ON my_table
instead of INSERT,UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

.......
END 
---------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger_after_del ON my_table
after DELETE
AS
BEGIN

.......
END
```